# Fusion Tables javascript chart not working

Tags: javascript, html, charts, data-visualization, fusioncharts

I am new to javascript and not great at coding in general. I have been trying to use javascript code I got from Fusion Charts to create a doughnut chart but it isn't working. I've tried using both a separate .js file with a src in html, and placing the javascript code in script tags within the html. The javascript doesn't show up on the webpage for either. It's probably something really simple.

```
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

(and my javascript)

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'doughnut2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '450',
    height: '450',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Homicides by Weapon",
            "subCaption": "USA 2013",
            "numberPrefix": "",
            "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",
            "showBorder": "0",
            "use3DLighting": "0",
            "showShadow": "0",
            "enableSmartLabels": "0",
            "startingAngle": "310",
            "showLabels": "0",
            "showPercentValues": "1",
            "showLegend": "1",
            "legendShadow": "0",
            "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
            "defaultCenterLabel": "Total homicides: 11583",
            "centerLabel": "Homicides from $label: $value",
            "centerLabelBold": "1",
            "showTooltip": "0",
            "decimals": "0",
            "captionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontBold": "0"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "Firearms",
                "value": "8454"
            }, 
            {
                "label": "Knives or cutting instruments",
                "value": "1490"
            }, 
            {
                "label": "Personal Weapons (hands, fists, etc.)",
                "value": "687"
            },
            {
                "label": "Other",
                "value": "952"
            }


        ]
    }
}).render();
});
```

Comment: Have you included fusioncharts.js in the project and referred it in the html?  Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

To render FusionCharts you need to add FC library in head tag.
please have a try to use cdn link [FC 3.10.1 Library](http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js) 
or you can use below code to render fusionchart

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first chart using FusionCharts Suite XT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'doughnut2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '450',
    height: '450',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Homicides by Weapon",
            "subCaption": "USA 2013",
            "numberPrefix": "",
            "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
            "bgColor": "#ffffff",
            "showBorder": "0",
            "use3DLighting": "0",
            "showShadow": "0",
            "enableSmartLabels": "0",
            "startingAngle": "310",
            "showLabels": "0",
            "showPercentValues": "1",
            "showLegend": "1",
            "legendShadow": "0",
            "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
            "defaultCenterLabel": "Total homicides: 11583",
            "centerLabel": "Homicides from $label: $value",
            "centerLabelBold": "1",
            "showTooltip": "0",
            "decimals": "0",
            "captionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
            "subcaptionFontBold": "0"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "label": "Firearms",
                "value": "8454"
            },
            {
                "label": "Knives or cutting instruments",
                "value": "1490"
            },
            {
                "label": "Personal Weapons (hands, fists, etc.)",
                "value": "687"
            },
            {
                "label": "Other",
                "value": "952"
            }


        ]
    }
}).render();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
</body>
</html>
```